# Убрать кавычки из текста

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Моё почтение, господа, такой вот вопрос. Допустим приходит переменная с текстом `let value = "Text"`. Существует ли какой небудь метод или способ чтобы убрать эти кавычки? К примеру, если бы `let value = Text`, то чтобы превратить содержимое переменной в текст, то понадобится метод `String(value)`, а мне нужно наоборот. Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Ничего не понятно.

Comment: Тогда вам нужно уточнить, в какой тип данных нужно превратить строку.

Comment: Всё равно ничего не понятно. Сделай [mcve].

Comment: @vsemozhebuty по сути у меня в переменной лежит часть кода, к примеру `let value = "function(a) { return a + 1}"`. Я передаю эту переменную в другой компонент и там мне надо, чтобы пришло `function(a) { return a + 1}`, то бишь, без кавычек, не строка, а часть кода.

Comment: Вам нужно подробнее описать это в вопросе. `String(value)` — это однозначная функция, превращающая всё в строку. Если вам нужно наоборот, из строки во что-то, нужно уточнять, во что — в число, в дату, или в функцию, как в вашем случае. В разных случаях превращение строки в функцию требует разных средств и связано с разными рисками и трудностями, так что опишите подробнее, тогда желающим будет легче помочь.

Comment: Похоже, автору нужна [темная сторона Силы](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval).

Comment: Господа, я нашёл альтернативный путь и благополучно решил эту проблему. Благодарю всех, кто принимал участие в решении данной проблемы.

Answer (score 0):

Могу предположить, что речь о

```
<Smth value={text} />
```

Comment: Сформулирую попроще, мне нужен способ или метод абсолютно протевоположный методу `String()`. Существует ли такой?